# Need help on Form Submission using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am learning jQuery and trying to submit a form in which - if the terms and conditions that pops up in a modal window are accepted, then submit the form, else close it.
I am using submit handler and ajax for form submission but it is not working (It is not taking me to the action URL). Can anyone please help. Here is the code :

```
<form action="www.google.com" method="post" id="registration" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="plain/text" autocomplete="off">

    ........        

</form>

<div class="modal hide" id="myModal" data-backdrop="false">

  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content"> 

     <div class="modal-header">
        .........
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">

            Please study the terms and conditions below and click "Yes" to Submit. Click "No" to cancel.

      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
      </div>         

    </div>

  </div>
</div>


$("#registration").validate({

        rules: {
            ......
        },

        messages: {
            .......
        },

        submitHandler: function(form){
            $.ajax({
                url: $(form).action,
                method: $(form).method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery.noConflict();
                    $("#myModal").modal('show');    
                    // Submit on clicking "Accept"
                    $("#myModal .btn-primary").click(function(){
                        //alert("Clicked on "Accept");
                        $("#myModal").modal('hide');// this is working
                        $(form).submit(); // this is not working
                    });
                }
            })
        }

        }); 

        return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

so first thing you need to do that you have to get ready all the parameters get on the  clicking **"Submit"** then just make an equivalent (sync / a sync) call on clicking of **"yes"** else don't call submitting and show some relative message to that

```js
function submitForm(){
    $("#submit").on('click',function(){
        // write your logic for getting all the informatioon from the form that you would like to submit
      
      //now write code for
      
      //  show the popup of confirmation.       else           
      
    });
    
    // make ajax call on click on "yes" of popup
  
    $("#yes").on('click,function(){
       
        // make ajax call here with parameters you get on click with sumit button's click
                 
    });    
    $("#no").on('click,function(){
       
        // write appropriate message or executuion you want.
                 
    });
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you want to achieve( expected result ) ...?

And Yes one thing that i don't know why are you using **" jQuery.noConflict(); "** because it's used when you may have clash with **jQuery** or **$** object

Comment: I don't need " jQuery.noConflict(); " now, it can be ignored. My expected behavior is - Fill the form and click "Submit", then I will get a modal window pop-up which shows the terms and conditions. When I click on "Yes" in the modal window, the form should submit and take me to the url in form action.